# "A crop grows" vs. "A crop is grown" — which is preferable?

Tags: passive-voice, active-voice

Consider following sentence-

*Tea grows both in Assam and Ceylon.*

It can be made better as-

*Tea grows **in both** Assam and Ceylon.*

Or-

*Tea **is grown in both** Assam and Ceylon.*

I am confused to decide which of them is best. According to text book answer-
*Passive voice is used when the subject does not do something himself. Active voice is used when the subject
does something himself. Here, Passive Voice should be used. Hence, tea is grown will be a correct usage.*

Comment: Well, that rather explains it, doesn’t it? If you say “tea is grown”, that means there’s an outside agent: human beings, who plant and actively grow the tea. If you say “tea grows”, there’s no agent: the tea plants just grow by themselves, quite naturally. Both sentences are true in Assam and Ceylon, where tea grows naturally and is grown by humans. So what is it that makes you think one option is _better_ than the other?

Answer (score 1):

I think all three examples are grammatical. As Janus out in the comments, the choice of which is best depends on what you want to express. The passive sentence implies that there is someone growing the tea. The active sentences could refer to either wild or cultivated tea.